# Reason for different punctuation of the prefix vav?

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk, aleph-bet-letters

In the Siddur, the prefix vav is seen with various punctuations (e.g., shva, kamatz, patah, shuruk).  When is each of these different punctuations used with a prefix vav and how does each affect the meaning of the prefix vav?

Comment: Are you asking about only the verb prefix, and not the conjunction?

Answer (score 13):

In biblical Hebrew:

- When preceding an imperfect (future-form) verb to make it past tense, the *vav* has a *patach*.
- However, that *patach* becomes a *kamatz* before an *alef*.
- Otherwise, when the word is the last in a phrase and has its stress on the syllable after the prefixed *vav*, that *vav* has a *kamatz*.
- If none of the above apply, the prefix has a *sh'va*, except that that *sh'va* changes to:

  - a *patach* if it's preceding a word that starts with a guttural *chataf patach*
  - a *kamatz* if it's preceding a word that starts with a *chataf kamatz*
  - a *tzere* or sometimes *segol* if it's preceding a word that starts with an *alef-chataf segol*
  - a *segol* if it's preceding a word that starts with a *chataf segol* (not on an *alef*)
  - a *chirik* if it's preceding a word that starts with a *yod-sh'va*
  - make the *vav* a *shuruk* if it's preceding a word that starts with a *sh'va* (not on a *yod*)
  - make the *vav* a *shuruk* if it's preceding a word that starts with the letter *bes*, *mem*, *pe*, or *vav*

Most of these rules can be found in [Gesenius §104](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/104._Conjunctions), which states them more precisely and also gives examples.

The *sidur* follows the above rules when quoting biblical passages. It strays in some ways from biblical grammar in more modern parts of the *sidur*, but — and this is just my impression — I don't think that the above rules of how to punctuate *vav* are among those strayings.