# לָ vs. לַ vs. לְ and וָ vs. וַ vs. וְ

Tags: grammar-dikduk, torah-reading, megillat-esther

What are the differences in meaning between the prefix of the letter ל (lamed), when different vowels are used [i.e. לַ (patach), לָ (kumatz) and לְ (shva)]? What about variants of the usage of the letter ו (vav) as a prefix?

Comment: Partial duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/114705/reason-for-different-punctuation-of-the-prefix-vav?rq=1

Comment: Is this on topic?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding *vav*, see msh210's answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/114709/14850).

Regarding *lamed*, Wikipedia has a nice article discussing [prefixes in Hebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefixes_in_Hebrew). A short summary follows, but see there for all the details:

1. *Lamed* meaning 'to' normally takes a *sheva*, although there are exceptions for cases when the next letter of the word has a specific vowel (e.g. before a *sheva* the *lamed* instead takes a *chirik* (e.g. לִירוּשָׁלִַם)).
2. If the meaning is 'to the' one might have expected to see a *lamed* followed by a *heh ha-yedi'ah*. What actually happens is that the *heh* falls away and the *lamed* takes the vowel that would have appeared under the *heh* (normally a *patach* (e.g. לַמָּקוֹם) but, for instance, before an *'ayin* a *kamatz* (e.g. לָעִיר)).